# Custom API ValidationAttribute for class property

Tags: c#, asp.net, validationattribute

I have a class Student that contains the list of property 'TextPair' as shown below:

```
public class Student
{
    public List<TextPair> Hobbies { get; set; }
    public List<TextPair> Languages { get; set; }
    public List<TextPair> Majors { get; set; }

}

public class TextPair
{
    [StringLength(2, ErrorMessage = "The value length is invalid")]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Here, I validate the value for maximum length 2 using the StringLength AttributeValidator and decorate in the property 'Value' inside TextPair model.
The problem for me is that the length is always fixed and length is always mandatory.

In my use case, I want the different flavor of Value in different part of the application (or, different property of same type) to support different lengths.

I was looking for something like below where I could pass the validation in my class where I declare my property 'TextPair'
[i.e. I don't want to make the validation mandatory always and also not hard-code the value 2]

```
public class Student
{
    //Any length of the value is accepted for hobbies
    public List<TextPair> Hobbies{ get; set; }

    [ValuesLength(Length = 2, ErrorMessage = "Language code length must be 2 characters max")]
    public List<TextPair> Languages { get; set; }

    [ValuesLength(Length = 128, ErrorMessage = "The major should be within 128 characters length")]
    public List<TextPair> Majors{ get; set; }

}
```

Is there any efficient way to approach this solution?

Comment: I don't believe that's possible only by using attributes. You _need_ to hard-code it (or use a const which is the same thing) because attributes are just metadata about that member/type that you are decorating. Maybe you can go for runtime validation by doing it inside get&set?

Comment: Is there a limited amount of classes that need this? Will you need a constant amount of lengths? Let's say you had 3 `TextPair` classes with different names and attribute values, would that solve the problem?

Comment: @FurkanKambay The example posted here is to only reflect the requirement of the same class ie. TextPair to handle different length validations for the value attribute. 
In real application, TextPair model is widely used in different classes, but yes I do need the validation only in few (around 3-4 places) class and all other classes do not even need to validate the length. 
Though I don't want to repeat the same code by creating different class and attribute names, Can you propose your approach to implement the feature using different classes.

Comment: I was thinking of making `TextPair` a base class with virtual properties and having a `LongTextPair` as a derived class and overriding just the `Value` property and decorating it with the new attribute values. So when you create your Students, you can go like this: `List<LongTextPair> Majors` or `List<MediumTextPair> Majors` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solution approached is as follows:

```
public class Student
{
    //Any length of the value is accepted for hobbies
    public List<TextPair> Hobbies{ get; set; }

    [ValuesLength(MaximumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "Language code length must be 2 characters max")]
    public List<TextPair> Languages { get; set; }

    [ValuesLength(MaximumLength = 128, ErrorMessage = "The major should be within 128 characters length")]
    public List<TextPair> Majors{ get; set; }

}
```

My Custom Attribute validation is checking the list and verifying if anyone of the element values are exceeding the provided length as:

```
public class ValuesLengthAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public int MaximumLength { get; set; }
        public override Boolean IsValid(object value)
        {
            Boolean isValid = true;
            var list = value as List<TextPair>;
            if (list != null && list.Count>0)
                foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    if (item.Value.Length > MaximumLength)
                        isValid = false;
                }

            return isValid;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try subclassing `StringLengthAttribute` to create your desired `ValuesLength` attribute. Please note that this code is not tested and is just suggestion to final implementation.

```
public class ValuesLength : StringLengthAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var isValid = true;

        var pair = value as TextPair;
        if (pair != null && pair.Value != null)
        {
            var pairValue = pair.Value;
            isValid = pairValue.Length < MaximumLength && pairValue.Length > MinimumLength;
        }        

        return IsValid ? ValidationResult.Success : new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```